# .htaccess does not work correctly on live server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use Laravel and Codeigniter at the same time, both the Laravel and Codeigniter would be in a subfolder of the public_html root.

I am trying to setup the .htaccess so that accessing `example.com/events` will redirect to Laravel `events/public` directory.

Here is my .htaccess file inside `public_html`, there is no other .htaccess file.

```
# for laravel assets inside events/public/{types}/{files}.{ext}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.ttf|\.woff)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ events/public/$1 [L]

# for laravel controller actions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} events
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.ttf|\.woff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ events/public/index.php [L]

# for codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^assets(.*)$ mycommerce/assets$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^themes(.*)$ mycommerce/themes$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^sitemap/(.*\.xml)$ mycommerce/xmls/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule !^index.php|assets|xmls|themes.*$ index.php
```

The CI one works fine, issue is only in Laravel. The controller actions works fine, I can see my controller in action, but all assets referenced by the controller view is showing 404. **The 404 is showing CI 404, not apache default 404 nor Laravel 404**.

Example URL would be:
`http://example.com/events/manage/events`
`http://example.com/events/js/app.js`

Any help would be appreciated, I've been dealing with this issue since yesterday. The code inside .htaccess above works on my local machine, however the live server seems to be not working properly.

Thank You!

Comment: the `^events/(.*)$ events/public/<...>` looks loopable. I'd try a negative lookahead in the regexp: `^events/(?!public)(.*)$ events/public/<...>`

Comment: Thank you for commenting @Deadooshka, I tried your suggestion but it still not found. Note the error is 404, not 500 usually infinite redirect.

Comment: I got 500 with those two rules without `(?!public)`. Apache 2.4.25. Also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} events` looks meaningless since allways matches the path passed thru the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Also this `^events/(.*)$ events/public/index.php`. If you take a submask then it should be appended to the script path as a parameter/path_info. Otherwise remove the `(.*)$`.